# TiXmlElement loses its child elements when stored

Tags: c++, xml, tinyxml

I'm trying to set up basic dynamic object construction for a game I'm making in c++ for a class. I've nearly got it working, however, the way that I have it set up for now requires me to generate objects from an XML file. In order to create them dynamically and not all at once, what I'm trying to do is store the initialization data of the objects (in a GAME_OBJECTFACTORY_INITIALIZERS struct called initializers) that need to be dynamically generated in a "prefab" map that gets used later, i.e. when the object needs to be instantiated.

The issue that I'm having is with the TiXmlElement* levelElement that is part of these initializers. It gets passed into my object factory's Create method, so that the child elements can be looped through to make the relevant components. This works for statically generated objects, i.e. anything but "Arrow" in this case.  However, when I store the initializers for the arrow in the prefabs map (within initializers is the levelElement reference), all of levelElement's ChildElements are NULL, which means that the object gets created without any components.

I know there are a lot of moving parts that are hard to succinctly descirbe, but I'll try and provide all the code that's relevant.

Arrow's GameAsset XML

```
<GameAsset name="Arrow"> //read in as "levelElement"
    <Component name="Sprite"/> //read in as "componentElement"
    <Component name="Body" x="0.0f" y="0.0f" angle="0.0f" bodyType = "dynamic"
           objectShape = "rectangle" density = "0.5f" friction = "0.0f"
           restitution = "1.0f" angularDamping = "0.0f" linearDamping = "0.0f"/>
    <Component name="Arrow"/>
</GameAsset>
```

Relevant code from Game.LoadLevel (levelElement is put into initializers)

```
    //...

    //Gets the first game asset element as child of the level element
    TiXmlElement* levelElement = (levelConfig.FirstChildElement("Level1"))->FirstChildElement("GameAsset");

    //...

    //Checks each levelElement
    while (levelElement != NULL) {
        //Sets up the shared initializers (others set in ObjectFactory.create())
        GAME_OBJECTFACTORY_INITIALIZERS initializers;
        initializers.levelElement = levelElement;

        //...other stuff added to initializers...

        if (std::string(levelElement->Attribute("name")) != "Arrow") {
            //Creates and initializes the new object with data from XML file, puts it into objects
            objects.push_back(oFactory->create(initializers));
        }
        else {
            //puts arrow in prefabs to be created later
            prefabs[std::string(levelElement->Attribute("name"))] = initializers;
        }

        levelElement = levelElement->NextSiblingElement("GameAsset");
    }
```

Game.Update (tells objectfactory (oFactory) to create prefabed arrow if the event is triggered) Prefabs.at("Arrow") gets the initializers.

```
//Creates an arrow from prefabs
if (iDevice->GetEventStatus(GAME_ARROW_FIRED)) {
    //When passing levelElement in using initializers here, it loses reference to its children. :(
    objects.push_back(oFactory->create(prefabs.at("Arrow")));
}
```

Lastly, to show where the error is visible, here is the beginning of ObjectFactory.Create, where it tries to get the first child element from initializers.levelElement.

```
std::shared_ptr<Object> ObjectFactory::create(GAME_OBJECTFACTORY_INITIALIZERS initializers) {

//Gets the first component element of the game asset element
TiXmlElement* componentElement = (initializers.levelElement->FirstChildElement("Component"));

//***Here, componentElement is NULL for an "Arrow." 
// However, it correctly obtains the child for objects that are created
// immediately after levelElement is stored in initializers.
```

Basically, I'm unsure what I'm doing wrong, here, because I'm passing levelElement the same way in both cases. The only difference is that for dynamic objects, I store the initializers in a map instead of immediately passing them to ObjectFactory.Create. Either way the levelElement is getting stored in initializers. But, I only lose the ability to reference it's children for the prefabbed one: and note, everything else in initializers (including levelElement itself) is correct.

Any ideas on how to fix this, or what might be causing the issue? I hope I was able to explain it clearly. Thanks so much in advance. If anything is confusing, let me know and I'll try to clarify.

---

EDIT: As requested, here is MCVE code for this issue. In this example, it stores the levelElement for Arrow in prefabs, creates a "Rock" (pushes "true" onto createReturns), then starts to loop Update. After trying to Create the Arrow, it breaks.

textXML.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<Level1>
  <GameAsset name="Arrow">
    <Component name="Component"/>
  </GameAsset>
  <GameAsset name="Rock">
    <Component name="Component"/>
  </GameAsset>
</Level1>
```

Source.cpp

```
#include "Game.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Game* game = new Game;

    std::string levelConfigFile = "testXML.xml";

    game->LoadLevel(levelConfigFile);

    for (;;) {
        game->Update();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Game.h

```
#pragma once

#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

#include"tinyxml/tinyxml.h"

//Initializers
struct GAME_OBJECTFACTORY_INITIALIZERS
{
    TiXmlElement* levelElement;
};

class Game {
public:
    Game();
    ~Game();

    bool LoadLevel(std::string);
    bool Update();
    bool Create(GAME_OBJECTFACTORY_INITIALIZERS);

private:
    std::map<std::string, GAME_OBJECTFACTORY_INITIALIZERS> prefabs; //<name, initializers>
    std::vector<bool> createReturns;
};
```

Game.cpp

```
#include "Game.h"

Game::Game(){}

Game::~Game(){}

bool Game::LoadLevel(std::string levelConfigFile)
{
    TiXmlDocument levelConfig(levelConfigFile.c_str());
    levelConfig.LoadFile();

    TiXmlElement* levelElement = (levelConfig.FirstChildElement("Level1"))->FirstChildElement("GameAsset");

    while (levelElement != NULL) {
        GAME_OBJECTFACTORY_INITIALIZERS initializers;
        initializers.levelElement = levelElement;

        if (std::string(levelElement->Attribute("name")) != "Arrow") {
            createReturns.push_back(Create(initializers));
        }
        else {
            prefabs[std::string(levelElement->Attribute("name"))] = initializers;
        }

        levelElement = levelElement->NextSiblingElement("GameAsset");
    }
    return true;
}

bool Game::Update()
{
    //Creates an arrow on update
    createReturns.push_back(Create(prefabs.at("Arrow")));
    return true;
}

bool Game::Create(GAME_OBJECTFACTORY_INITIALIZERS initializers)
{
    if(initializers.levelElement->FirstChildElement("Component")){
        return true;
    }
    else return false;
}
```

---

EDIT: I have tried to rework the code, so that initializers has a std::vector rather than a TiXmlElement*, and instead of giving it the levelElement, I populated the vector with levelElements child elements (Components). This didn't fix the problem, and trying to access the Attributes of those elements causes a crash ONLY for Arrow (still accessed from Prefabs).

Comment: Present your [MCVE] to proceed. I've worked with TinyXML and may be able to help, but the problem could be literally anywhere in your program.

Comment: I tried to provide as little as possible, but all of these snippets are relevant to the problem (I also tried to describe the code bits first to make it more clear). 

I felt it was necessary to include the XML itself, the place where levelElement is read and either added to prefabs or sent to objectfactory via initializers, the place where prefabs are used to call objectfactory.create(), and the place where I get NULL. All of those are part of the pipeline to the issue, so I'm not sure how to simplify further. This is less than 100 lines of code, including comments. :(

Comment: Please follow the link provided. A MCVE is self-contained and verifiable. Here you just provide little snippets, not part of any cohesive whole. Surely, in the process of debugging this problem so far, you have constructed a MCVE? If not, it's no surprise you are having trouble. :)

Comment: I made and added the code for one that should be standalone. (I think I misunderstood what you were suggest the first time, sorry about that).

Comment: That's a lot better; it could still be more condensed (one file, ideally). But at least now it's workable.